# Get QScrollBar Width upon change in QScrollBar Visibility

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to get the width of a qscrollbar as it changes visibility. I'm doing this because I want to change the width of my qtablewidget by the width of the qscrollbar if it is visible.

I'm using the `rangeChanged(int min, int max)` signal from my qscrollbar. If `max > min` then the qscrollbar is visible. My problem is that when I get the qscrollbar width using `m_tableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->width()` the value is not the current width, but rather the previous width before the rangeChanged signal was fired.

This is what my signal-slot connection looks like:

```
connect(m_tableWidget->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(rangeChanged(int,int)),
        this, SLOT(verticalScrollBarChanged(int,int)));
```

And this is the slot function:

```
void ImageTableWidget::verticalScrollBarChanged(int min, int max)
{
    int verticalScrollBarWidth = 0;
    if (max-min)
        verticalScrollBarWidth = m_tableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->width();

    int horizontalHeaderWidth = m_tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->length();
    m_tableWidget->setFixedWidth(verticalScrollBarWidth + horizontalHeaderWidth);
}
```

Does anyone know how I could obtain the new qscrollbar width at the time it becomes visible/invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has a better way of taking care of such async resize of some widget container area. You should probably remove all the code that explicitly takes care of it and instead add this:

```
// m_tableWidget constructed
// at least first parameter for horizontal sizing should be Expanding. 
m_tableWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

And for that table widget class it makes sense to overload resizeEvent virtual method which will be triggered with every resize and do the cells adjust from there or `resizeColumnsToContents()`.

Comment: I want two things to happen in my table, 1) I want the table cells to fit tightly to their contents (the result I get from using `resizeColumnsToContents`, and 2) I want the table width to fit tightly to the width of the horizontal header (i.e. no space after the last column AND no need for the horizontal scroll bar). Setting the Size Policy to Expanding does not give me these results.

Comment: The problem needs to be broken in parts: 1) How to automatically adjust the inner widget size. 2) How to adjust cells. I believe it is wrong to reject the simplest and effective #1 because you have not figured out #2. The question originally is about #1 though. And I cannot tell about #2 as long as I did not do that but pretty much did a lot of the rest.

Comment: I've already figured out how to adjust the cell sizes to my liking by using `resizeColumnsToContents`. I now just need to adjust the QTableWidget width to fit the total width of my displayed data. I'm going through all this trouble because I don't like how the vertical scrollbar covers some of my right most columns data when it appears. I have also hidden the horizontal scrollbar because I only have two columns to display. I simply need the width of the vertical scrollbar as it appears for me to complete the look I want.

Comment: That should be the other way around. For your QTableWidget I would try to overload resizeEvent method and given new size do the adjust for cells. And the size would be right without any scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderVX, I moved everything from my `verticalScrollBarChanged` function into the `resizeEvent` function and this worked perfectly.

Comment: I am glad as well. Accept the answer?